# One requestAnimationFrame invoked per redraw or multiple?

Tags: javascript, html

What happens when there are multiple requestAnimationFrame callbacks in relation to screen redraws?

With two requestAnimationFrame blocks i.e.

```
(function a() {
     requestAnimationFrame(a);
}())

(function b() {
     requestAnimationFrame(b);
}())
```

Will the sequence of execution be:

**1**:

```
 -> a
 -> b
 -> screen redrawn     
 -> a
 -> b
 -> screen redrawn
 ...
```

**2**:

```
 -> a
 -> screen redrawn   
 -> b
 -> screen redrawn     
 -> a
 -> screen redrawn
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting question. Based on my read, a `MozBeforePaint` event should be fired for each registered callback before proceeding to the next frame. To test, I modified your code slightly (**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/4L2kB/)**):

**HTML**

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

**CSS**

```
var aId, bId;

function a(ts) {
    console.log('a', ts);
    aId = requestAnimationFrame(a);
}

function b(ts) {
    console.log('b', ts);
    bId = requestAnimationFrame(b);
}

var startButton = document.getElementById('start');

var stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');

function stop() {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(aId);
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(bId);
}

function start() {
    a();
    b();
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', start);
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stop);
```

The output after clicking `start` seems to confirm that expectation. The first invocation of `a()` and `b()` log undefined timestamps, because they're starting the animation directly rather than responding to a callback. Each subsequent invocation of `a()` logs a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` that matches the one logged by the invocation of `b()`, suggesting strongly that it's the same event firing both callbacks.

**OUTPUT**

```
a undefined
b undefined
a 123182.04999999944
b 123182.04999999944
a 123198.73199999893
b 123198.73199999893
a 123215.22000000004
b 123215.22000000004
a 123231.9179999995
b 123231.9179999995
a 123248.59099999958
b 123248.59099999958
a 123265.21899999898
b 123265.21899999898
```

Caveats:

- I have no specific firsthand knowledge of the implementations; just my interpretation of the documentation and this test
- This test was executed in Mac OS X Chrome 35; other browsers may produce different results

Comment: Nice! Same results with Safari and Firefox on OSX. I guess the problem is... is it guaranteed to execute this way? Taking a game as an example: if the foreground and background draw on separate request callbacks they may not be drawn at the same time.

Comment: Yip. Confirmed, thanks. I edited your fiddle to lock up the browser every so often and can confirm that a and b are always called with the same timestamp: http://jsfiddle.net/rossc1/6Qcvb/1/